# How to force scattered UV tiles to 0-1 UV?

Tags: uv

The model was UV in a different app.
The UV are Tiled at a real world scale yet scattered so far apart they are not visible in UV scene view. (Home key cannot zoom far enough out to see all the UV tiles)
What are the options to keep the repeat tile scale yet force all the UV tiles to 0-1 space? This image shows a 1024 repeat tile image and how large the UV has to be to tile correctly. the top of the geometry is also in UV space...somewhere.
[image]
after scaling down the UV,(S,It's not visible in UV view-port. "Centralize" appears to work but i'm not sure if there are other ways to also focus the UV.
[image]0.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- select all faces <kbd>A</kbd>
- select all UV  <kbd>A</kbd> in image editor
- set pivot point to 2D cursor:

[image]

- scale it down, let's say, 10 times, by 0.1 (<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>) you may use another value if it is not enough
- use mapping node to compensate scaling:

[image]

note that *scale* is equal to scale that was used and *type* is *Textured*

Comment: Ok, that works to an extent. The problem is that after scaling down the UV, it's not centered or viewable, I cannot see the UV anymore. Home key only centers the UV space, not the UV map of the geometry. numpad"." is focused on something but it's not visible.

Comment: Oh ok. Before scaling set pivot point to 2D cursor, should help